# Apache2 - Friendly URLs

Tags: .htaccess, url, apache2

I am using this code for creating friendly urls:

```
rewriteengine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

It should work so I could go to http://www.mywebsite.com/test but when I go my url it just says `404 Not Found` but no error presents in the log file.

I am using Apache2 on Debian x86_64 and my question is do I need to change any settings for friendly urls to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many possibilities.  Here are a few (some of them from [SmartWebDeveloper.com](http://smartwebdeveloper.com/apache/htaccess-problems)):

- Make sure the `.htaccess` file is named correctly.  Make sure you didn't forget the `.` at the beginning, and that the file name is all lowercase.
- Make sure `AllowOverride` is set properly.  If you look in your config files (`httpd.conf`, and possibly other configuration files in the `/etc/apache2/` directory), you may see a line like this: `AllowOverride None`.  That line prevents your .htaccess file from changing things.  (Note that this line may be present in the server configuration in multiple places - including the main configuration, the web root directory configuration (probably in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`), and any VHost configuration files in the `sites-enabled` folder, so you need to find the one that is actually going to change things for this site.)  Change it to `AllowOverride FileInfo` (if all you need is rewrites) or `AllowOverride All` (if you plan to use your `.htaccess` for other things.)  A full description of `AllowOverride` is at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride
- Make sure the rewrite module is enabled.  If your rewrite configuration is enclosed in `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` and `</IfModule>` tags, or if your Apache is configured not to report `.htaccess` errors, you will not see anywhere that the module is disabled.  To enable it, use `a2enmod rewrite` and restart your Apache server.

Comment: I will try this as soon as my crappy host fixes my server.

Comment: I now have it working, thanks. What would you suggest to make my php include files load when someone goes to a url like this http://www.mysite.com/test/test - the problem with that is it's in a different directors so includes files are in different places.

Comment: @PHPDEV There are several different ways of doing that, but the comments here are not the right place to discuss it.  Look around on the site for more and ask another question if you need help.